# What is the best way to set up CI/CD for Xamarin Forms PCL Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

My Xamarin Forms PCL project is included a lot of DDL that requires to connect embedded devices. so i am working on to get an iOS/Android CI/CD set up.

1. I tried with MSBUILD plugin with Jenkins - its not always building and failing to build dependency projects.
2. I explored and found out that Cake Build is very good and started that. Still it failing.

Looking for any better solution for Xamarin PCL CI/CD other than Jenkins and build scripts.

I explored and found out that Cake Build is very good and started that. Still it failing.

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft solution for building apps? http://appcenter.ms

Comment: Try with Azure DevOps (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/) or AppCenter (https://appcenter.ms/).
It is quite straight forward, link your repo, setup which projects you want to build(add some conditions, prebuild/postbuild scripts, after build create deploy options for Android and iOS etc.).

Comment: Our repo is on-premise one. 
Can I use on-premises repositories?
App Center currently supports cloud hosted git repositories on Azure DevOps (formerly known as Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)), Bitbucket and Github, but does not support on-premises repositories.

Comment: I finally able to get everything working with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried Appcenter Build? 
https://appcenter.ms/apps

Comment: Our repo is on-premise one.
Can I use on-premises repositories?
App Center currently supports cloud hosted git repositories on Azure DevOps (formerly known as Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)), Bitbucket and Github, but does not support on-premises repositories.

Comment: Yes.. Currently Appcenter not supported on-premises repositories.

Comment: We used Gitlab's mirroring function to sync release branch to Bitbucket